# Android clipboard manager

Tags: android, clipboard

I have used Clipper Synch for long time. It works.

However I can not turn off the sync easily when I copy e.g. passwords. (I don't want private info in their cloud.)

I think it once had a turn off button but not after updates. You can now "detach device". I have tried, but it hangs for hours when It connects (synchs) again. After hours it could synch again.

I think maybe it has accumulated ALL my clippings, not the last 50 as I asked for.

Reinstall gives back all clippings, not possible to delete clippings in this way. Finally managed to delete all clippings but now synch hangs. The webpage will not load fully.

No email reply from developer.

TIME FOR A NEW CLIPBOARD MANAGER.

**I wish:**

- Synch with cloud that is easy to turn off and on. I use clippings for short time backup.
- You must be able to organize clippings in folders or lists, of course.
- Maybe also for other clippings than text?

Which is the best clipboard manager?

**Edit:**
I must add to the question, regarding Clipper Plus:
There is a switch off button. It appears if you tap and drag on the notification. I now got this reply from the developer. I don't find that information in the instructions. 
However, the list of clippings in the cloud is extremely long, including clippings that are 3 years old, even though I have deleted all clippings on the device. It has taken several days for my phone to start syncing, after reconnecting it.

Comment: I'm not using any, but be welcome to check with [my list of clipboard apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard) while waiting for fitting recommendations. There are several meeting at least one of your criteria – I'm just not sure which one meets them all together ;)

Comment: Thank you Izzy for always having constructive suggestions. I will check out your list.

Comment: Good luck! If you find your candidate, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Comment: @ycc_swe, please read the Crucial Security Edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Swiftkey keyboard for android allows you to see your recent copies, and swipe away ones that you want to delete, and pin ones that you don't want to expire after an hour.

Also, why are you using your clipboard for passwords at all? Android provides an input method paradigm that any password manager worth its salt can use to avoid clipboard spies (which exist on Android as well as Windows). I use Keepass2Android offline, but others like Blur can also directly type passwords without the need for the clipboard.

*Crucial Security Edit*: Not only using the clipboard for passwords is unnecessary, it is dangerous. The Android Clipboard isn't any more secure than, for instance, the Windows Clipboard because **any Android app or Service can access the clipboard and keep a record of past entries**, thus making clipboard spyware very easy to create.